# Is there any global mouse listener for the web?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to move an electron application to the web. But the electron app tracks mouse clicks and plays it to the user. I want that same functionality on the web.

I am currently using the following library to do this.
https://github.com/wilix-team/iohook

Is there any way to do global tracking for a web app?

I am using `React`. I need basically need to store on what part of the screen a user pressed. So it must work when the user clicks on any other app and not just the browser

I am basically tracking clicks in a screen recorder. So I can highlight them in the video. Using recordRtc for the recording.

Is this possible to do in any way?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the user to share their screen via [WebRTC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API). Then use the [Screen Capture API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen_Capture_API/Using_Screen_Capture) to capture the entire screen, including outside the web browser.

Comment: Thanks! Can i still record if user click anywhere on the screen. I just want to record the x and y position where the user clicks on the screen

Comment: @RamManiChimuriya the screen capture API is Screen recording. So you’d be able to see the mouse clicks as a video stream rather than get x and y coordinates specifically. What are you building?

Comment: I want to record the clicks so I can use them as metadata for processing the video that I record, processing will include splitting the video based on clicks into chunks for further processing. I just need to store the position on the screen where the click was done and the timestamp of when it was done.

Comment: Yes but what does the whole system do?

Comment: Records a video, split the video into chunks based on clicks, and process the individual chunks to convert voice to text and then create subtitles for the video.